# How to test what was submitted when a key piece, 'form' tag, no longer exists?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I recently changed my code to make it more responsive and as such messed up my jQuery code to record correct vs incorrect answers to a small quiz. The javascript that I posted below used to work just fine when the question was located in an HTML form tag. How can I modify the jQuery code in the second line (where the 'answer1' variable is declared) to work properly now that a form tag no longer surrounds my question? Thanks very much.

**HTML**

```
<div class="intro-header2">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>The capital of Croatia is ...</h1>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>

        <div class="radio" style="margin-top: 0px;">
          <label><input type="radio" name="capital" value="zagreb" id="zagrebID">&nbsp; Zagreb</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio" style="margin-top: 10px;">
          <label><input type="radio" name="capital" value="debrovnik">&nbsp; Debrovnik</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio" style="margin-top: 10px;">
          <label><input type="radio" name="capital" value="makarska">&nbsp; Makarska</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio" style="margin-top: 10px;">
          <label><input type="radio" name="capital" value="moscow">&nbsp; Moscow</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio" style="margin-top: 20px;">
          <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="&nbsp; Next &nbsp;" id="NextID">
        </div>
    </div> <!--/.container-->
</div> <!--/.intro-header2-->
```

**JS**

```
$("#NextID").click(function(){
        var answer1 = ($('input[name=capital]:checked', '#myForm').val());
        if (answer1 == "zagreb") {
            var QuestionNumber = "Question 1, The capital of Croatia.";
            var QuizDesc = "Quiz questions on the country of Croatia.";
            var name = localStorage.getItem('name');
            var email = localStorage.getItem('email');

            //pulls the current counter from local storage
            var counter = localStorage.getItem('counter');
            //adds one to it
            var counter = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('counter')) + 1;
            //updates the global variable for counter
            setCounter(counter);

            passedQues(email, name, QuestionNumber, QuizDesc);
            document.location.replace("page3.html");
            }

        else if (!$("input[name='capital']:checked").val()) {
            alert('Nothing is checked!');
            return false;
    }

        else {
            var QuestionNumber = "Question 1, The capital of Croatia.";
            var QuizDesc = "Quiz questions on the country of Croatia.";
            var name = localStorage.getItem('name');
            var email = localStorage.getItem('email');

            //pulls the current counter from local storage
            var counter = localStorage.getItem('counter');
            //adds one to it
            var counter = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('counter')) + 0;
            //updates the global variable for counter
            setCounter(counter);

            failedQues(email, name, QuestionNumber, QuizDesc);
            document.location.replace("page3.html");
            }
    });
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You no longer have the `form` element, and I assume that it has an `id` attribute with the value `myForm`

This line looks for the value of an `input` inside a an element with id `myForm`

```
var answer1 = ($('input[name=capital]:checked', '#myForm').val());
```

This element no longer exists, so the input value is not found. Try changing this line to:

```
var answer1 = ($('input[name=capital]:checked').val());
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I tried it again with your code and it still misses the mark. When I answer the question with the correct answer (zagreb), it still ignores that part of the if statement and jumps to the else which is what to do when it is something other than zagreb is selected. Thanks again.

Comment: You need to check for errors in your code. I am sure the answer is read correctly (see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gm5bwvmb/)

Comment: Yep, you were right. It works perfectly. Thanks for the help!

Comment: great! glad I could help.